# Getting Last Unique Value and Additional Information from Another

Tags: mysql

I have two tables;

- Webpages - a table containing url and name of a number of sites
- Access - table containing the access times, client IPs and url of which site they accessed

I need to get a hold of the last X (lets say 10) accesses to any given webpage, that was a unique combination of ip and url. So if a user connects to one page multiple times, this should only be listed as one (lets say the latest) row.

I have a query that gets me the result that I need, but it is EXTREMELY slow. In order for me to get 10 of the last unique accesses, it takes around 45 seconds.

This is the query;

```
select ma.access_date, mp.name 
from access ma, webpages mp
where ma.url = mp.url 
and ma.id = (select max(id) 
             from access ma2 
             where ma2.client_id = ma.client_id 
             and ma2.url = ma.url)
order by ma.id desc 
limit 10;
```

How could I optimize this? Is there some flaw in my query or am I completely on the wrong track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By moving the (correlated) subquery, you can reduce the data to be read considerably:

```
SELECT
    a.access_date,
    w.name
FROM
    (SELECT
        client_id,
        url,
        MAX(id) id
    FROM
        access
    GROUP BY
        client_id, url
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 10
    ) s
JOIN
    access a
    USING (client_id, url, id)
JOIN
    webpages w
    USING (url)
```

Comment: With some minor editing this works perfectly and now runs in 0.25 seconds. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an index on the field "url" on both tables:

```
CREATE INDEX url_access ON access (url);
CREATE INDEX url_webpages ON webpages (url);
```

This should decidedly improve the performance of your query ([here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) is why).